# Summary of ArrayList ordering in Kotlin (Android)

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I am trying to provide a summary of items within an ArrayList (where order matters). Basically, I am setting up an exercise plan with two different types of activities (Training and Assessment). I then will provide a summary of the plan after adding each training/assessment to it.

The structure I have is something along the lines of:

```
exercisePlan: [
    {TRAINING OBJECT},
    {TRAINING OBJECT},
    {ASSESSMENT OBJECT},
    {TRAINING OBJECT}
]
```

What I want to be able to do is summarise this in a format of:
`2 x Training, 1 x Assessment, 1 x Training`, which will be displayed in a TextView in a Fragment. So I will have an arbitrarily long string that details the structure and order of the exercise plan.
I have tried to investigate using a HashMap or a plain ArrayList, but it seems pretty messy so I'm looking for a much cleaner way (perhaps a MutableList). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayList is just a specific type of MutableList. It's usually preferable to use a plain List, because mutability can make code a little more complex to work with and keep robust.

I'd create a list of some class that wraps an action and the number of consecutive times to do it.

```
enum class Activity {
    Training, Assessment
}

data class SummaryPlanStep(val activity: Activity, val consecutiveTimes: Int) {
    override fun toString() = "$consecutiveTimes x $activity"
}
```

If you want to start with your summary, you can create it and later convert it to a plain list of activities like this:

```
val summary: List<SummaryPlanStep> = listOf(
    SummaryPlanStep(Activity.Training, 2),
    SummaryPlanStep(Activity.Assessment, 1),
    SummaryPlanStep(Activity.Training, 1),
)

val plan: List<Activity> = summary.flatMap { List(it.consecutiveTimes) { _ -> it.activity } }
```

If you want to do it the other way around, it's more involved because I don't think there's a built-in way to group consecutive duplicate elements. You could a write a function for that.

```
fun <T> List<T>.groupConsecutiveDuplicates(): List<Pair<T, Int>> {
    if (isEmpty()) return emptyList()
    val outList = mutableListOf<Pair<T, Int>>()
    var current = first() to 1
    for (i in 1 until size) {
        val item = this[i]
        current = if (item == current.first)
            current.first to (current.second + 1)
        else {
            outList.add(current)
            item to 1
        }
    }
    outList.add(current)
    return outList
}

val plan: List<Activity> = listOf(
    Activity.Training,
    Activity.Training,
    Activity.Assessment,
    Activity.Training
)

val summary: List<SummaryPlanStep> = plan.groupConsecutiveDuplicates().map { SummaryPlanStep(it.first, it.second) }
```

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04, I'll try this way. I'll comment what I currently have in case others find it more useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have set up to work for me at the moment:

```
if (exercisePlanSummary.isNotEmpty() && exercisePlanSummary[exercisePlanSummary.size - 1].containsKey(trainingAssessment)) {
        exercisePlanSummary[exercisePlanSummary.size - 1][trainingAssessment] = exercisePlanSummary[exercisePlanSummary.size - 1][trainingAssessment]!! + 1
    } else {
        exercisePlanSummary.add(hashMapOf(trainingAssessment to 1))
    }

    var textToDisplay = ""
    exercisePlanSummary.forEach {
        textToDisplay = if (textToDisplay.isNotEmpty()) {
            textToDisplay.plus(", ${it.values.toList()[0]} x ${it.keys.toList()[0].capitalize()}")
        } else {
            textToDisplay.plus("${it.values.toList()[0]} x ${it.keys.toList()[0].capitalize()}")
        }
    }
```

where `trainingAssessment` is a `String` of `"training"` or `"assessment"`. `exercisePlanSummary` is a `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Int>>`.

What @Tenfour04 has written above is perhaps more appropriate, and a cleaner way of implementing this. But my method is quite simple.